# How to set the width of buttons with dynamic text equal width as the widest button inside a div?

Tags: css

If I have a div that contains a bunch of div that has button inside, like the following

```
<div class="cmp-buttongroup">
  <div class="item0 button">
     <button class="cmp-button">      
        <span class="cmp-button__text">one</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="item1 button">
      <button  class="cmp-button">
        <span class="cmp-button__text">two</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="item2 button">
     <button class="cmp-button">      
        <span class="cmp-button__text">three</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have three buttons, but the number of buttons can be any. It can be 3, 4, 5, etc.
The width of the button is totally controlled by the length of text inside the button.
What is cleanest way to give each of the button equal width as the widest button, in this case, the last button "three"? Assuming that I cannot change the HTML.

Comment: use `box-sizing: border-box;` and specify the max-width and min-width in the css for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign fix width for the button in your css. For eg:

```
.button{
    Width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: What if I don't use fixed with? The width should be dynamics since button text is dynamic.

Comment: Than u can use max-width. It makes it responsive